# To get the exact filename without the prefix of parent folders while using client Boto3 SDK

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to use the exact filename of a json file for some other task which has a path name like: `folder1/folder2/txt.json`.
I just want to retrieve `txt.json` name using some attribute of `boto3` but I am not able to find any such attribute.
This can be done easily by split method in python but I want to know if this can be done using `boto3` as well while listing the objects?

Answer (score 1):

> This can be done easily by split method in python

Yes, that's the **correct way** of doing this. S3 API just returned the entire key of your object, which is "folder1/folder2/txt.json". Its up to you to process it the way you want.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is no actual file structure in S3 - the /directory/directory/directory is just shown as a file structure as a connivence for users - in reality it is a flat storage system.  So, as noted by this answer, Split is the only way to do so because to s3 there is no such thing as directories - just a Key for that object